# Prevent and/or detect cycles in postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, recursive-query

Assuming a schema like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE node (
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name     VARCHAR,
  parentid INT REFERENCES node(id)
);
```

Further, let's assume the following data is present:

```
INSERT INTO node (name,parentid) VALUES
('A',NULL),
('B',1),
('C',1);
```

Is there a way to prevent cycles from being created? Example:

```
UPDATE node SET parentid = 2 WHERE id = 1;
```

This would create a cycle of `1->2->1->...`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739150/to-find-infinite-recursive-loop-in-cte

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your trigger simplified and optimized, should be considerably faster:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION detect_cycle()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
      WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(parentid, path, cycle) AS ( -- relevant columns
          -- check ahead, makes 1 step less
         SELECT g.parentid, ARRAY[g.id, g.parentid], (g.id = g.parentid)
         FROM   node g
         WHERE  g.id = NEW.id  -- only test starting from new row
         
         UNION ALL
         SELECT g.parentid, sg.path || g.parentid, g.parentid = ANY(sg.path)
         FROM   search_graph sg
         JOIN   node g ON g.id = sg.parentid
         WHERE  NOT sg.cycle
         )
      SELECT FROM search_graph
      WHERE  cycle
      LIMIT  1  -- stop evaluation at first find
      )
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Loop detected!';
   ELSE
     RETURN NEW;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

You don't need dynamic SQL, you don't need to count, you don't need all the columns and you don't need to test the whole table for every single row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER detect_cycle_after_update
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON node
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE detect_cycle();
```

An `INSERT` like this has to be prohibited, too:

```
INSERT INTO node (id, name,parentid) VALUES (8,'D',9), (9,'E',8);
```

Comment: This is great! How would one go about making it "generic"? That is, passing in the fields that represent id and parent_id? Then the same function could be used for any self-referential table.

Comment: I am wondering HOW a single INSERT can create a cycle? Because there is no possibility that your uncreated node has a child. Leaves can not create cycles. @Erwin Brandstetter

Comment: @İsmailYavuz: True, since referential integrity is enforced with an FK constraint, a single-row insert can never create a cycle. But multi-row inserts can. (Like the example at the end of my post.) FK constraints are checked after every *command* by default. And the suggested trigger catches that.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I was trying to use this approach (with extra check) to avoid cycles in my self-referential foreign key. The check is, there is way to disable the parent linkage using a field, let's say, `linkage_overridden`. If that is `true`, then foreign constraint won't be used, and even though `parent_id == id` check is true, there won't be a cycle. How would that kind of check work here? I was trying to update `g.parentid = ANY(sg.path)` condition with: `g.parentid = ANY(sg.path) and g.linkage_overridden = false`, but it's not working.

Comment: @RohitJain: Please present your case with all relevant information as new question. You can always link to this one for context.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, I came up with a trigger that prevents this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION detect_cycle() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
  loops INTEGER;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(id, parentid, name, depth, path, cycle) AS (
        SELECT g.id, g.parentid, g.name, 1,
          ARRAY[g.id],
          false
        FROM node g
      UNION ALL
        SELECT g.id, g.parentid, g.name, sg.depth + 1,
          path || g.id,
          g.id = ANY(path)
        FROM node g, search_graph sg
        WHERE g.id = sg.parentid AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT count(*) FROM search_graph where cycle = TRUE' INTO loops;
IF loops > 0 THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Loop detected!';
ELSE
  RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER detect_cycle_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON node
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE detect_cycle();
```

So, if you try to create a loop, like in the question:

```
UPDATE node SET parentid = 2 WHERE id = 1;
```

You get an `EXCEPTION`:

```
ERROR:  Loop detected!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION detect_cycle()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
  cycle int[];
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(%4$I, path, cycle) AS (
  SELECT g.%4$I, ARRAY[g.%3$I, g.%4$I], (g.%3$I = g.%4$I)
    FROM %1$I.%2$I g
   WHERE g.%3$I = $1.%3$I
  UNION ALL
  SELECT g.%4$I, sg.path || g.%4$I, g.%4$I = ANY(sg.path)
    FROM search_graph  sg
    JOIN %1$I.%2$I g ON g.%3$I = sg.%4$I
   WHERE NOT sg.cycle)
SELECT path
  FROM search_graph
 WHERE cycle
 LIMIT 1', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, quote_ident(TG_ARGV[0]), quote_ident(TG_ARGV[1]))
INTO cycle
USING NEW;
IF cycle IS NULL
THEN
  RETURN NEW;
ELSE
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Loop in %.% detected: %', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, array_to_string(cycle, ' -> ');
END IF;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER detect_cycle_after_update
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON node
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE detect_cycle('id', 'parent_id');
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

While the current accepted answer by @Erwin Brandstetter is ok when you process one update/insert at a time, it still can fail when considering concurrent execution.

Assume the table content defined by

```
INSERT INTO node VALUES
(1, 'A', NULL),
(2, 'B', 1),
(3, 'C', NULL),
(4, 'D', 3);
```

and then in one transaction, execute

```
-- transaction A
UPDATE node SET parentid = 2 where id = 3;
```

and in another

```
-- transaction B
UPDATE node SET parentid = 4 where id = 1;
```

Both UPDATE commands will succeed, and you can afterwards commit both transactions.

```
-- transaction A
COMMIT;
```

```
-- transaction B
COMMIT;
```

You will then have a cycle 1->4->3->2->1 in the table.
To make it work, you will either have to use isolation level SERIALIZABLE or use explicit locking in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

slightly different from [Erwin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26672812/15603477)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION detect_cycle ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $func$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( WITH RECURSIVE search_graph (
            id,
            name,
            parentid,
            is_cycle,
            path
) AS (
            SELECT *, FALSE,ARRAY[ROW (n.id,n.parentid)]                    
            FROM
                node n
            WHERE
                n.id = NEW.id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                n.*,
                ROW (n.id,n.parentid) = ANY (path),
                path || ROW (n.id,n.parentid)
                    
            FROM
                node n,
                search_graph sg
            WHERE
                n.id = sg.parentid
                AND NOT is_cycle
)
            SELECT * 
            FROM
                search_graph
            WHERE
                is_cycle
            LIMIT 1) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Loop detected!';
ELSE
    RETURN new;
END IF;
END
$func$;
```