# To find infinite recursive loop in CTE

Tags: sql, recursive-cte

I'm not a SQL expert, but if anybody can help me.

I use a recursive CTE to get the values as below.

Child1 --> Parent 1

Parent1 --> Parent 2

Parent2 --> NULL

If data population has gone wrong, then I'll have something like below, because of which CTE may go to infinite recursive loop and gives max recursive error. Since the data is huge, I cannot check this **bad data** manually. Please let me know if there is a way to find it out.

Child1 --> Parent 1

Parent1 --> Child1

or

Child1 --> Parent 1

Parent1 --> Parent2

Parent2 --> Child1

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't specified the dialect or your column names, so it is difficult to make the perfect example...

```
-- Some random data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MyTable

CREATE TABLE #MyTable (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, ParentID INT NULL, Description VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #MyTable (ID, ParentID, Description) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'Parent'), -- Try changing the second value (NULL) to 1 or 2 or 3
(2, 1, 'Child'), -- Try changing the second value (1) to 2 
(3, 2, 'SubChild')
-- End random data

;WITH RecursiveCTE (StartingID, Level, Parents, Loop, ID, ParentID, Description) AS
(
    SELECT ID, 1, '|' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|', 0, * FROM #MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R.StartingID, R.Level + 1, 
        R.Parents + CAST(MT.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|',
        CASE WHEN R.Parents LIKE '%|' + CAST(MT.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        MT.*
        FROM #MyTable MT
        INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE R ON R.ParentID = MT.ID AND R.Loop = 0
)

SELECT StartingID, Level, Parents, MAX(Loop) OVER (PARTITION BY StartingID) Loop, ID, ParentID, Description 
    FROM RecursiveCTE 
    ORDER BY StartingID, Level
```

Something like this will show if/where there are loops in the recursive cte. Look at the column `Loop`. With the data as is, there is no loops. In the comments there are examples on how to change the values to cause a loop.

In the end the recursive cte creates a `VARCHAR(MAX)` of ids in the form `|id1|id2|id3|` (called `Parents`) and then checks if the current `ID` is already in that "list". If yes, it sets the `Loop` column to 1. This column is checked in the recursive join (the `ABD R.Loop = 0`).

The ending query uses a `MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` to set to 1 the `Loop` column for a whole "block" of chains.

A little more complex, that generates a "better" report:

```
-- Some random data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MyTable

CREATE TABLE #MyTable (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, ParentID INT NULL, Description VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #MyTable (ID, ParentID, Description) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'Parent'), -- Try changing the second value (NULL) to 1 or 2 or 3
(2, 1, 'Child'), -- Try changing the second value (1) to 2 
(3, 3, 'SubChild')
-- End random data

-- The "terminal" childrens (that are elements that don't have childrens
-- connected to them)
;WITH WithoutChildren AS
(
    SELECT MT1.* FROM #MyTable MT1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #MyTable MT2 WHERE MT1.ID != MT2.ID AND MT1.ID = MT2.ParentID)
)

, RecursiveCTE (StartingID, Level, Parents, Descriptions, Loop, ParentID) AS
(
    SELECT ID, -- StartingID 
        1, -- Level
        '|' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|', 
        '|' + CAST(Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|', 
        0, -- Loop
        ParentID
        FROM WithoutChildren
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R.StartingID, -- StartingID
        R.Level + 1, -- Level
        R.Parents + CAST(MT.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|',
        R.Descriptions + CAST(MT.Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|', 
        CASE WHEN R.Parents LIKE '%|' + CAST(MT.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '|%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        MT.ParentID
        FROM #MyTable MT
        INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE R ON R.ParentID = MT.ID AND R.Loop = 0
)

SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE 
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL OR Loop = 1
```

This query should return all the "last child" rows, with the full parent chain. The column `Loop` is `0` if there is no loop, `1` if there is a loop.

Comment: Don't even try to give a perfect answer if the question is far from perfect. Your efforts are appreciated.

Answer (score 45):

With Postgres it's quite easy to prevent this by collecting all visited nodes in an array.

Setup:

```
create table hierarchy (id integer, parent_id integer);

insert into hierarchy
values
(1, null), -- root element
(2, 1), -- first child
(3, 1), -- second child
(4, 3), 
(5, 4), 
(3, 5); -- endless loop
```

Recursive query:

```
with recursive tree as (
  select id, 
         parent_id, 
         array[id] as all_parents
  from hierarchy
  where parent_id is null
  
  union all
  
  select c.id, 
         c.parent_id,
         p.all_parents||c.id
  from hierarchy c
     join tree p
      on c.parent_id = p.id 
     and c.id <> ALL (p.all_parents) -- this is the trick to exclude the endless loops
)
select *
from tree;
```

---

To do this for multiple trees at the same time, you need to carry over the ID of the root node to the children:

```
with recursive tree as (
  select id, 
         parent_id, 
         array[id] as all_parents, 
         id as root_id
  from hierarchy
  where parent_id is null
  
  union all
  
  select c.id, 
         c.parent_id,
         p.all_parents||c.id, 
         p.root_id
  from hierarchy c
     join tree p
      on c.parent_id = p.id 
     and c.id <> ALL (p.all_parents) -- this is the trick to exclude the endless loops
     and c.root_id = p.root_id
)
select *
from tree;
```

#### Update for Postgres 14

Postgres 14 introduced the (standard compliant) `CYCLE` option to detect cycles:

```
with recursive tree as (
  select id, 
         parent_id
  from hierarchy
  where parent_id is null

  union all

  select c.id, 
         c.parent_id
  from hierarchy c
     join tree p
      on c.parent_id = p.id 
)
cycle id -- track cycles for this column
   set is_cycle -- adds a boolean column is_cycle
   using path -- adds a column that contains all parents for the id
select *
from tree
where not is_cycle
```

As mentioned [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-CYCLE), this syntax is a shortcut equivalent to adding an `is_cycle` and `path` array rows manually.

Comment: The most clean solution.

Comment: Agree with @adrian-mitev: this is elegant simplicity; should be the accepted answer, IMO.

Comment: @VictoriaStuart: the accepted answer is for SQL Server and although Interstellar never confirmed it, it's safe to assume that she/he is using that, so this answer is probably not suitable.

Comment: Given that I have multiple parent hierarchy (https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2017/10/18/hierarchy-with-multiple-parents/), is there any option for me to use similar solution? Obviously I can't add `id` to `all_parents`, since this might be still valid `id` for different `parent` in my multiple parents hierarchy.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue: you need to include the ID of the root node in the check. See my edit (untested)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternate method for detecting cycles in adjacency lists (parent/child relationships) where nodes can only have one parent which can be enforced with a unique constraint on the child column (`id` in the table below).  This works by computing the closure table for the adjacency list via a recursive query.  It starts by adding every node to the closure table as its own ancestor at level 0 then iteratively walks the adjacency list to expand the closure table.  Cycles are detected when a new record's child and ancestor are the same at any level other than the original level zero (0):

```
-- For PostgreSQL and MySQL 8 use the Recursive key word in the CTE code:
-- with RECURSIVE cte(ancestor, child, lev, cycle) as (

with cte(ancestor, child, lev, cycle) as (
  select id, id, 0, 0 from Table1
  union all
  select cte.ancestor
       , Table1.id
       , case when cte.ancestor = Table1.id then 0 else cte.lev + 1 end
       , case when cte.ancestor = Table1.id then cte.lev + 1 else 0 end
    from Table1
    join cte
      on cte.child = Table1.PARENT_ID
   where cte.cycle = 0
) -- In oracle uncomment the next line
-- cycle child set isCycle to 'Y' default 'N'
select distinct
       ancestor
     , child
     , lev
     , max(cycle) over (partition by ancestor) cycle
  from cte
```

Given the following adjacency list for Table1:

```
| parent_id | id |
|-----------|----|
|    (null) |  1 |
|    (null) |  2 |
|         1 |  3 |
|         3 |  4 |
|         1 |  5 |
|         2 |  6 |
|         6 |  7 |
|         7 |  8 |
|         9 | 10 |
|        10 | 11 |
|        11 |  9 |
```

The above query which works on SQL Sever (and Oracle, PostgreSQL and MySQL 8 when modified as directed) rightly detects that nodes 9, 10, and 11 participate in a cycle of length 3.

SQL(/DB) Fiddles demonstrating this in various DBs can be found below:

- [Oracle 11gR2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aca4b8/1)
- [SQL Server 2017](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64cb1/1)
- [PostgeSQL 9.5](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c8f5d/1)
- [MySQL 8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2cbdecf83e089acb026afcb871e67c92)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same approach described by Knuth for detecting a cycle in a linked list here. In one column, keep track of the children, the children's children, the children's children's children, etc. In another column, keep track of the grandchildren, the grandchildren's grandchildren, the grandchildren's grandchildren's grandchildren, etc.

For the initial selection, the distance between `Child` and `Grandchild` columns is 1. Every selection from `union all` increases the depth of `Child` by 1, and that of `Grandchild` by 2. The distance between them increases by 1.

If you have any loop, since the distance only increases by 1 each time, at some point after `Child` is in the loop, the distance will be a multiple of the cycle length. When that happens, the `Child` and the `Grandchild` columns are the same. Use that as an additional condition to stop the recursion, and detect it in the rest of your code as an error.

SQL Server sample:

```
declare @LinkTable table (Parent int, Child int);
insert into @LinkTable values (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (7, 1);

with cte as (
    select lt1.Parent, lt1.Child, lt2.Child as Grandchild
    from @LinkTable lt1
    inner join @LinkTable lt2 on lt2.Parent = lt1.Child
    union all
    select cte.Parent, lt1.Child, lt3.Child as Grandchild
    from cte
    inner join @LinkTable lt1 on lt1.Parent = cte.Child
    inner join @LinkTable lt2 on lt2.Parent = cte.Grandchild
    inner join @LinkTable lt3 on lt3.Parent = lt2.Child
    where cte.Child <> cte.Grandchild
)
select Parent, Child
from cte
where Child = Grandchild;
```

Remove one of the `LinkTable` records that causes the cycle, and you will find that the `select` no longer returns any data.

Comment: What if the loop is such that the child is never equal to the grandchild? I.e, cycles longer than 2 nodes? Will this solution still work then?

Comment: @avl_sweden Yes. Edited to include a hopefully clearer explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to limit the recursive result

```
WITH EMP_CTE AS
( 

    SELECT 
        0 AS [LEVEL],   
        ManagerId, EmployeeId, Name
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        [LEVEL] + 1 AS [LEVEL],
        ManagerId, EmployeeId, Name
    FROM Employees e
    INNER JOIN EMP_CTE c ON e.ManagerId = c.EmployeeId 
 AND s.LEVEL < 100 --RECURSION LIMIT
) 

    SELECT  * FROM EMP_CTE WHERE [Level] = 100
```

Comment: This solution, leveraging a `level` counter, works also for SQL dialects that (unlike Postgres) do not have the `ARRAY` function. For example, for me it works with #snowflake.
+1 thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for SQL Server:

Table Insert script:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    [ID] INT,
    [ParentID] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable
(
    [ID],
    [ParentID],
    [Name]
)
VALUES
(1, NULL, 'A root'),
(2, NULL, 'Another root'),
(3, 1, 'Child of 1'),
(4, 3, 'Grandchild of 1'),
(5, 4, 'Great grandchild of 1'),
(6, 1, 'Child of 1'),
(7, 8, 'Child of 8'),
(8, 7, 'Child of 7'), -- This will cause infinite recursion
(9, 1, 'Child of 1');
```

Script to find the exact records which are the culprit:

```
;WITH RecursiveCTE
AS (
   -- Get all parents: 
   -- Any record in MyTable table could be an Parent
   -- We don't know here yet which record can involve in an infinite recursion.
   SELECT ParentID AS StartID,
          ID,
          CAST(Name AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS [ParentChildRelationPath]
   FROM MyTable
   UNION ALL

   -- Recursively try finding all the childrens of above parents
   -- Keep on finding it until this child become parent of above parent.
   -- This will bring us back in the circle to parent record which is being
   -- keep in the StartID column in recursion
   SELECT RecursiveCTE.StartID,
          t.ID,
          CAST(RecursiveCTE.[ParentChildRelationPath] + ' -> ' + t.Name AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS [ParentChildRelationPath]
   FROM RecursiveCTE
       INNER JOIN MyTable AS t
           ON t.ParentID = RecursiveCTE.ID
   WHERE RecursiveCTE.StartID != RecursiveCTE.ID)

-- FInd the ones which causes the infinite recursion
SELECT StartID,
       [ParentChildRelationPath],
       RecursiveCTE.ID
FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE StartID = ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Output of above query:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your example you can just use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to prevent an infinite loop. Here is why https://stackoverflow.com/a/77165059/17885973. However, infinite loops can still occur if the returned data is more complex than just the IDs of children and parents.