# Prevent infinite loop in recursive query in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Here: ([To find infinite recursive loop in CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739150/to-find-infinite-recursive-loop-in-cte/31745768#31745768)) is a discussion how to prevent an infinite loop in a recursive query. There the recursion is prevented on the "query level" - at least in an answer about Postgresql.

Is there a way in Postgresql (10) to implement some kind of safety net to prevent infinite recursions? Is it a feasible way to use `statement_timeout` for this or is there any other widely accepted way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In my development environment, I always use two fuses for recursive queries or functions. My client automatically sets on startup

```
set statement_timeout to '10s'
```

It is very rare that I need more and quite often it saves me from a dead loop.

When I write a recursive query from scratch I always use an additional column that limits the number of levels involved, something like this:

```
with recursive cte (root, parent, depth) as (
    select id, parent_id, 1
    from ...
union all
    select c.id, t.parent_id, depth+ 1
    from ...
    where depth < 10
)
select * 
from cte;
```

In production both these ways may be problematic. Instead, you can adjust the value of the configuration parameter [max_stack_depth (integer)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html) to the anticipated needs and capabilities of the operating system and/or hardware.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31745768/1995738) for an alternative approach and example of the new feature in Postgres 14+.

Comment: Thank you! This helps :)

Comment: The depth setting was immensely helpful in seeing my own errors in a Redshift recursive CTE.  Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

For parent-child relationships, simply replacing `UNION ALL` with `UNION` prevents an infinite loop in recursive queries if you are interested in parent and child IDs only. I doubt that `UNION ALL` is very useful in recursive queries at all. Here is algorithm described on PostgreSQL site:

> 1. Evaluate the non-recursive term. For `UNION` (but not `UNION ALL`),
>    discard duplicate rows.
>    Include all remaining rows in the result of the
>    recursive query, and also place them in a temporary working table.
> 2. So long as the working table is not empty, repeat these steps:
>
>    - **(a)** Evaluate the recursive term,
>      substituting the current contents of
>      the working table for the recursive self-reference.
>      For `UNION` (but not `UNION ALL`),
>      discard duplicate rows and rows that duplicate any
>      previous result row. Include all remaining rows in the result of the
>      recursive query, and also place them in a temporary intermediate
>      table.
>    - **(b)** Replace the contents of the
>      working table with the contents of the
>      intermediate table, then empty the intermediate table.

Here 2.a ensures that duplicates are discarded while evaluating the recursive term, so the infinite loop breaks at this point.

Comment: replacing UNION ALL with UNION gives: 
Recursive common table expression ... does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.(42000,252)

Comment: I had the same problem and was searching for an answer. Replacing UNION ALL to UNION worked for me, thank you!

Comment: @Ben, I believe you use SQL Server. The original question was specific to PostgreSQL, and my answer was based solely on that. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with how it's implemented in SQL Server