# Is it posible to create hierarchy but with multiple rows in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I can do a hierarchy with one row result (using a query from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58586400/12273235)) but I have no idea where to start when it has multiple rows.

So here's my table:

```
     id|  parent_id|                      name|
-------|-----------|--------------------------|
      1|     [NULL]|             United States|
      2|     [NULL]|                     Japan|
      3|          1|                  New York|
      4|          3|                  Brooklyn|
      5|          6|               Los Angeles|
      6|          1|                California|
      7|          6|                     Dixon|
      8|          2|                     Kyoto|
      9|          2|                     Tokyo|
```

`name` which has null `parent_id` is a grand parent. So, how to make a query which generated result like this?

```
                   Country|    States/Province|           City|
|-------------------------|-------------------|---------------|
|            United States|           New York|       Brooklyn|
|            United States|         California|    Los Angeles|
|            United States|         California|          Dixon|
|                    Japan|              Kyoto|         [NULL]|
|                    Japan|              Tokyo|         [NULL]|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple self join on the table because the number of levels you are interested in is limited:

```
select co.name as country,
       p.name as "State/Province", 
       ct.name as city
from hierarchy co
  left join hierarchy p on p.parent_id = co.id
  left join hierarchy ct on ct.parent_id = p.id
where co.parent_id is null
order by co.name;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/UON36358